# Is it possible to corrupt somehow data in iOS AddressBook via AB API?

Tags: ios, abaddressbook

To write some fields with strange symbols, for instance. Did anyone come across such issues? I'm evaluating an opportunity of storing my custom string field in iPhone AB and I want to know, if there is any risk to corrupt AB.

UPD:

I mean, can I do something that bad with AB data, so Contacts.app stops working?

Answer (score 1):

Hey 
I have an app that stores data in the address book. Of course you can corrupt the user data if you are not careful with your coding. As for the address book API apple gave the developers the ability to do almost everything and bad coding can even delete or manipulate the wrong contacts etc.
 Apple has some guide lines in the address book documentation that can help you treat the user address bok carefully.
The only way for you to do it right is to read the docomanttion  carfolly and test your application well before you distribute  it

Comment: And if it does it wrong, you shouldn't worry as Apple will simply disapprove your app.